The presentation of jsconfig.json prevent VSCode from auto import when using react-icons
I was starting a javascript react project, I used react-icons. I found an interesting bug, when I add a jscofig.json at root folder, the auto import doesn't work, like this:

If I remove the jsconfig.json file, it works.

My question is why this happens? And how should I solve this problem?
